# Rails javascript include not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm installing a new bootstrap admin theme on an application.

It works perfectly if I include my javascript files at the end of the application body div like this

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'app.min.e05f769f' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'plugins-init' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'switchery-settings' %>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'js/jquery.dataTables.min' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'js/dataTables.bootstrap.min' %>

<%= content_for?(:extra_scripts) ? yield(:extra_scripts) : nil %>
```

But If I include them via application.js like this I got a different result.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': true %>
<%= content_for?(:extra_scripts) ? yield(:extra_scripts) : nil %>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks

//= require bootstrap-sprockets

//= require js/lib.min

//= require app.min.e05f769f
//= require plugins-init
//= require switchery-settings

//= require js/jquery.dataTables.min
//= require js/dataTables.bootstrap.min

//= require_tree ./app

//= require cocoon

//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

Here my navbar links and all javascript related features are disabled I get this kind of errors in my console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:33719
    at application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:33719
    at application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:33719
highcharts-settings-26359110f393fbb0aa6bc3ffc41875fe5db4fc6e893003c0d7288e770583925c.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Dashboard is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (highcharts-settings-26359110f393fbb0aa6bc3ffc41875fe5db4fc6e893003c0d7288e770583925c.js:3)
    at u (lib.min-500a1a89656394ee5528d8f981d621eff7f09d649a35d99223d0f6eb23e011f5.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (lib.min-500a1a89656394ee5528d8f981d621eff7f09d649a35d99223d0f6eb23e011f5.js:2)
    at Function.ready (lib.min-500a1a89656394ee5528d8f981d621eff7f09d649a35d99223d0f6eb23e011f5.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.s (lib.min-500a1a89656394ee5528d8f981d621eff7f09d649a35d99223d0f6eb23e011f5.js:1)
clients:3096 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at clients:3096
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:31315)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:5227)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:4879)
    at Object.trigger (application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:5131)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:5861)
    at Function.each (application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:371)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:138)
    at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:5860)
    at HTMLDocument.onLoad (application-7bd22507ed6202d2c9cdc970588f95759f6c5c6eaa7703cae22cbf0a7af22c5a.js:31320)
```

What is the difference the 2 methods and what is the correct way to include those files ?

[image: my current hierarchy]

Comment: what is your assets folder structure ?

Comment: I updated with screenshots of my assets folder hierarchy

Comment: I believe rather to add `/= require js/jquery.dataTables.min`, it should be `/= require vendor/js/jquery.dataTables.min` Also put vendor folder inside Javascript folder. can you please try it ?

Comment: vendor does not only javascript but also css and fonts. Want me to test with a javascripts/vendor folder with only the js files ?

Comment: yes. can you please try with it ? it seems hight chart and data table javascript in not found.

Comment: No changes. I still got the same errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144373/discussion-between-anand-soni-and-lrp).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't catch turbolinks events in your JS files. Much like you need to use `$(document).ready()` for jQuery, all JS code should only be execute after the `turbolinks:load` event fired. For example:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  MyApp.init()
```

Comment: Not sure to understand how this works. Could you give me a little more details ? (I updated application.js in the question like the one I'm using right now)